# processing text in jTextArea

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to implement a Document Listener in my program. So far every time the user types in a new word, I am getting the whole text and saving it. What I want to do is to get only the new word/words typed in and process them. Can you give me suggestions how I can do that?

Comment: I think that the DocumentListener provides a pretty clear API (insert/remove). What part don't you get in that? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I understand how DocumentListener works. What I don't get is how to catch a whole word typed in. At the moment I am catching every single letter, separately, that the user types in. This is why in order to process each word of the text, I need to get the whole text of the document every time there is a change.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? What will you do with these words once you capture them? Have you tried using a Scanner on the text retrieved? Or doing simple tests looking for whitespace?

Comment: Hovercraft Full of Eels, I will try with your suggestion and use a Scanner. What I want is to check every newly typed word whether it is a stop word or not(and,but,if,etc). Because I don't want to overwhelm the application by capturing the whole text every time there is a change I wanted to see if there is any way of capturing just any newly typed word. Then find out whether it is a stop word or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is proposed code similar to yours above:

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.Document;


//public class DocumentListener {       // Fix: not a good name for the class since it is part of JVM
  public class DocumentEventDemo extends JFrame {   // easier than extends JPanel
      JPanel txtPanel, centerPanel;
      GridLayout grid;

      JTextField txtField;
      JTextArea txtArea;
      JFrame frame;
      JComponent newContentPane;

      FlowLayout flow;

      public DocumentEventDemo() {

          txtArea = new JTextArea();
          txtArea.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new MyDocumentListener());
          txtArea.getDocument().putProperty("txtArea", "MyDocumentListener");

//        txtField = new JTextField(10);    // 10 chars max
//        txtField.setText("12345");

          centerPanel = new JPanel();
          grid = new GridLayout(2,1,1,1);

          txtPanel = new JPanel();
          flow = new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER);
          txtPanel.setLayout(flow);

          //Adding control GUI fields to the only panel
          // txtPanel.add(txtArea);
          // txtPanel.add(txtField);


          // Forming the center view with GUI controls
          centerPanel.setLayout(grid);
//        centerPanel.add(txtPanel);
          centerPanel.add(txtArea);

          // Add Panels to the Frame
          getContentPane().add(centerPanel,"Center");

          this.setSize(500,200);
          this.validate();
          this.setVisible(true);
          setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

//        newContentPane = getRootPane();
//        newContentPane.setOpaque(true);
//        frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);

}

    //MyEditor editor = new MyEditor(); // what is MyEditor?

    //javax.swing.event.DocumentListener mydocumentListener = new javax.swing.event.DocumentListener()

    // Make a class to define the inherited abstract methods, which are also events.
    class MyDocumentListener implements DocumentListener {
       String[] word=new String[50];
       String text; 
       int i=0;
       int y;
       int l;
       int len;

       public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent documentEvent) {
           System.out.println("The text has been changed.");
       }

       public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent documentEvent) {
           try {
               GetWord(documentEvent);
           } catch (BadLocationException ex) {
               Logger.getLogger(DocumentListener.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
           }
       }

       public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent documentEvent) {
           System.out.println("A character has been removed!");
       }

      private void GetWord(DocumentEvent documentEvent) throws BadLocationException {
          //get the type of event
          DocumentEvent.EventType type = documentEvent.getType();
          //check what is the event, hence what is the user doing  
          if (type.equals(DocumentEvent.EventType.INSERT)) {
              Document source = documentEvent.getDocument();

              y=documentEvent.getOffset();
              l=documentEvent.getLength();
              len=source.getLength();

              text = source.getText(y,l);
              if(text.equals(" "))
              {
                  for (int z=0;z<len;z++)
                  {
                      System.out.print(word[z]);
                  }
                  System.out.println("\n");
                  Arrays.fill(word,null); 
                  i=0;
              }

              word[i]=text;
              i++;
          } else  {
              System.out.println("A character has been removed!");
          } 
      }
    };  // DocumentListener class instantiation


//  editor. editArea.getDocument().addDocumentListener(mydocumentListener);


    public static void main(String args[]){
        new DocumentEventDemo();
    }

}   // TOP class
```

---

Notes:

- My most outer class extends JFrame, which creates the window & listeners the easy way, I think.
- DocumentEventDemo is a constructor that creates the UI controls and looks.
- I created a class that implements DocumentListener. This way I can override the abstract events.
- My main function is on the bottom inside the class DocumentEventDemo, like yours actually.
- I do not see the code for class MyEditor. Therefore I replaced that with JTextArea, behaves like an editor.
- Your code GetWord seems to be working well. Congratulations!
- Your technique of using System.out.println is not working since the app is windows GUI application instead of console, which works well with System.out.
- Obviously, you still have work to do with the Listener functions for changed and remove.

Have fun!

Tommy Kwee

Comment: @curious,  I would like to give a suggestion. I noticed you seem frustrated that others may be angry at you, especially when you see a score of -4 for the question. One reason is that the question is too broad or vague. It does not specify your problem. The question seems like a student with homework or a professional with a task but does not want to take effort to learn. We like to see people take an effort to learn.
If I see code from the questioner, then I can understand the problem & the question better. And I will sympathize with the person more, of course.  Continue...

Comment: @curious,  Continued...There were two problems, I think, in the original issue. First, getting the texts from the Document object and second, creating the UI with the listeners. That was not obvious from the original question. But at least now, we get to this stage after couple cycles between us.

btw, I too am learning the Swing UI library. A good Sun Oracle document I think is http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/overview-tree.html .

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanations. I really appreciate this. I will try to upload code from now on when I am asking for help. I did not upload anything here earlier because I was not asking for a fix rather than for alternatives, but maybe when you saw my code you got a better idea of what I needed:) I am glad to hear that others are learning the Swing UI just like me:) I will be checking out the other threads and try to help out to others as well :)

Comment: Tell me which code structure you end up implementing. Try them both, and you can learn a lot more.  Have fun with it.

Comment: I used your code because mine was not allowing me to do something I wanted with the code!!! :) Thanks a lot!!! :) I am slowly progressing!!! :)

Comment: @curious, I am glad you're learning! Thanks for your feedback and best vote. This is the only way to learn. I like your comment and voted for it. Another, there r few good ways to make the Swing GUI work. Learn ALL ways a moment at a time. And then you can see the plus/minus of various methods.  bye

Answer (score 1):

How about document at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html ?
Basically, the parameter DocumentEvent from insertUpdate event contains the text. You will have to retrieve the texts from the object e.

My suggestion is to try out some code and we'll see how much you know about DocumentListener, ok?

Comment: @curious, I reviewed your code below and it is not the same code structure as http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/events/DocumentEventDemoProject/src/events/DocumentEventDemo.java. This would work for events processing. Besides that, I will propose code similar to yours. Pls be patient.

Comment: thanks :) I actually tried to follow the code in the link above, but ... Anyway, the code is kind of working now I am in the process of improving it.

Comment: @ The Original Android, I finally understand what you meant by "it is not the same structure"!!!!!! This comment helped me sort out an issue that appear with my code!!!! Thanks for noting that!!!